Use Thom Isomorphism to calculate the compact cohomology of Möbius band
This comes from exercise 12.11 of Bott and Tu.

Exercise 12.11 Apply the Thom isomorphism (12.2) to compute the cohomology with compact support of the open Möbius strip.


Theorem 12.2 (Thom Isomorphism) For $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ any vector bundle of rank $n$ over $M$ and $\mathfrak{U}$ a good cover of $M$, $H^{*}_{cv}(E) \cong H^{*-n}(\mathfrak{U},\mathfrak{H}^n_{cv})$,
where $\mathfrak{H}^n_{cv}$ is the presheaf $\mathfrak{H}^n_{cv}(U)=H^n_{cv}(\pi^{-1}U)$.

I know how to calculate the compact cohomology of the Möbius strip using MV sequence, but how do we apply the Thom isomorphism here?

The Mobius strip is a rank $1$ bundle over the circle, no?

@FShrike I am not sure if the compact cohomology on the Mobius strip itself is the same as the compact vertical cohomology over $S^1$

@JeffreyMak It is the same since the base space is compact.

I had a one-month hiatus off algebraic topology. Here I try to give a solution to my own question.
Choose a good cover $\mathfrak{U}= \{U_0, U_1, U_2 \}$ of $S^1$ as given.

Let $\pi : E \rightarrow S^1$ be the Möbius strip, a rank 1 vector bundle over $S^1$. We may give E a Riemannian metric.
For later convenience, construct a trivilization for $\mathfrak{U}$. On the open set $U_\alpha$, pick a consistent positive direction on the fiber. On each fiber, points are assigned the distance from the zero section, up to a $\pm$ sign. This gives a trivilization $\varphi_\alpha: E|_{U_\alpha} \rightarrow U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}$, with transition maps $g_{\alpha \beta}=\{\pm 1 \}$.
Thinking pictorically, either all three transition maps give -1 or only one of them gives -1.
Consider the case where only one of the transition maps is negative. 
Without loss of generality, say $g_{01}=g_{12}=1$, $g_{02}=-1$. The case where all three transition maps are -1 follows exactly the same argument.
Notice that if $U$ is contractible, then $\mathfrak{H}^1_{cv}(U):=H^1_{cv}(\pi^{-1}U) \cong H^0(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. 
Next, $\mathfrak{H}^1_{cv}(U)$ is generated by a form which integrates to 1 on each fiber, and is compact along the vertical direction.
Choose such forms $\{\eta_\alpha \}$. On $U_{01}, U_{12}$, orientation is unambiguous; on $U_{02}$, choose the orientation induced by $U_0$.
A cocycle in $C^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathfrak{H}^1_{cv})$ can always be represented by $(a\eta_0, b\eta_1, c\eta_2)$, where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$.
$\delta (a\eta_0, b\eta_1, c\eta_2)=0$ implies that the difference between the forms on the intersections are exact, and hence integrate to zero when restricted to any fiber. So the following equations hold:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} a\eta_0 - b\eta_1=0$
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} b\eta_1 - c\eta_2=0$
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} c\eta_2 - a\eta_0=0$

which implies:

$a-b=0$
$b-c=0$
$a+c=0$ (this equation is different from the others due to orientation considerations)

So $a=b=c=0$. This means $ker\ \delta=0$, implying that $H^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathfrak{H}^1_{cv})=H^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathfrak{H}^1_{cv})=0$
